# android app crashing upon launching on device

Tags: android

i see a black screen (the app has launched). Here is what i think is the important part in the logcat:

```
 05-29 21:37:47.536: I/dalvikvm(2461): Could not find method android.view.View.animate, referenced from method com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving.MainScreenActivity$3.onVisibilityChange
    05-29 21:37:47.536: W/dalvikvm(2461): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3690: Landroid/view/View;.animate ()Landroid/view/ViewPropertyAnimator;
    05-29 21:37:47.536: D/dalvikvm(2461): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0027
    05-29 21:37:47.536: D/dalvikvm(2461): VFY: dead code 0x002a-0037 in Lcom/asymptoticnerds/smartliving/MainScreenActivity$3;.onVisibilityChange (Z)V
    05-29 21:37:47.536: D/dalvikvm(2461): VFY: dead code 0x0042-0044 in Lcom/asymptoticnerds/smartliving/MainScreenActivity$3;.onVisibilityChange (Z)V
    05-29 21:37:47.546: D/InputTransport(289): Input channel constructed: name='40c8cc08 com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving/
```

almost the entire logcat:

```
 05-29 21:37:40.589: I/StatusBarPolicy(404): onSignalStrengthsChanged
        05-29 21:37:44.843: E/AlarmManagerService(289): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=0, 1369877904.801000000
        05-29 21:37:44.843: V/AlarmManager(289): sending alarm Alarm{4095f430 type 0 com.android.vending}
        05-29 21:37:44.863: V/AlarmManager(289): pending wakeup alarm com.android.vending
        05-29 21:37:44.973: D/AndroidRuntime(2363): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
        05-29 21:37:44.973: D/AndroidRuntime(2363): CheckJNI is OFF
        05-29 21:37:44.973: D/AndroidRuntime(2363): setted country_code = Canada
        05-29 21:37:44.973: D/AndroidRuntime(2363): setted sales_code = TLS
        05-29 21:37:44.973: D/AndroidRuntime(2363): found sales_code tag = <TLS>, </TLS> 
        05-29 21:37:44.973: D/dalvikvm(2363): creating instr width table
        05-29 21:37:45.063: D/LibQmg_native(2363): register_android_app_LibQmg
        05-29 21:37:45.073: D/DeviceEncryption(2363): JNI: register_android_deviceencryption_DeviceEncryptionManager
        05-29 21:37:45.103: D/AndroidRuntime(2363): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
        05-29 21:37:45.103: D/AndroidRuntime(2363): Shutting down VM
        05-29 21:37:45.113: D/dalvikvm(2363): GC_CONCURRENT freed 103K, 70% free 312K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 0ms+1ms
        05-29 21:37:45.113: D/dalvikvm(2363): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
        05-29 21:37:45.313: D/AndroidRuntime(2387): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
        05-29 21:37:45.313: D/AndroidRuntime(2387): CheckJNI is OFF
        05-29 21:37:45.313: D/AndroidRuntime(2387): setted country_code = Canada
        05-29 21:37:45.313: D/AndroidRuntime(2387): setted sales_code = TLS
        05-29 21:37:45.313: D/AndroidRuntime(2387): found sales_code tag = <TLS>, </TLS> 
        05-29 21:37:45.313: D/dalvikvm(2387): creating instr width table
        05-29 21:37:45.404: D/LibQmg_native(2387): register_android_app_LibQmg
        05-29 21:37:45.414: D/DeviceEncryption(2387): JNI: register_android_deviceencryption_DeviceEncryptionManager
        05-29 21:37:45.434: D/dalvikvm(289): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1345K, 44% free 7515K/13319K, external 874K/2154K, paused 3ms+4ms
        05-29 21:37:45.444: D/AndroidRuntime(2387): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
        05-29 21:37:45.474: D/dalvikvm(2254): GC_EXPLICIT freed 48K, 50% free 2739K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 20ms
        05-29 21:37:45.474: D/VoldCmdListener(166): volume aseced /mnt/sdcard/external_sd
        05-29 21:37:45.474: D/MountService(289): getAsecVolumeState :: result = unmounted
        05-29 21:37:45.484: I/DmAppInfo(289): getApplicationsList found row counts : 0 For Pkg : com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving
        05-29 21:37:45.504: D/dalvikvm(1029): GC_CONCURRENT freed 17K, 43% free 3982K/6919K, external 0K/0K, paused 2ms+2ms
        05-29 21:37:45.504: D/dalvikvm(2254): GC_EXPLICIT freed 6K, 50% free 2740K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 21ms
        05-29 21:37:45.504: D/VoldCmdListener(166): volume aseced /mnt/sdcard/external_sd
        05-29 21:37:45.504: D/MountService(289): getAsecVolumeState :: result = unmounted
        05-29 21:37:45.504: W/ActivityManager(289): No content provider found for: 
        05-29 21:37:45.524: D/PackageParser(289): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl-211820315.tmp
        05-29 21:37:45.524: W/ActivityManager(289): No content provider found for: 
        05-29 21:37:45.584: D/PackageManager(289): Scanning package com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving
        05-29 21:37:45.584: I/PackageManager(289): Unpacking native libraries for /data/app/com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving-1.apk
        05-29 21:37:45.594: D/installd(178): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving-1.apk' ---
        05-29 21:37:45.614: D/dalvikvm(2401): creating instr width table
        05-29 21:37:45.624: D/dalvikvm(514): GC_EXPLICIT freed 255K, 49% free 3012K/5895K, external 0K/0K, paused 27ms
        05-29 21:37:45.694: D/Finsky(1029): [1] 5.onFinished: Installation state replication succeeded.
        05-29 21:37:45.814: D/dalvikvm(2401): DexOpt: load 28ms, verify+opt 136ms
        05-29 21:37:46.224: D/installd(178): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving-1.apk' (success) ---
        05-29 21:37:46.224: D/PackageManager(289):   Activities: com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving.MainScreenActivity
        05-29 21:37:46.224: I/ActivityManager(289): Force stopping package com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving uid=10094
        05-29 21:37:46.455: I/installd(178): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving-1.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving-1.apk@classes.dex
        05-29 21:37:46.455: D/PackageManager(289): New package installed in /data/app/com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving-1.apk
        05-29 21:37:46.565: D/Launcher.LauncherModel(449):   --> add package
        05-29 21:37:46.565: D/Launcher.LauncherModel(449): application intent received: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED, replacing=false
        05-29 21:37:46.565: D/Launcher.LauncherModel(449):   --> package:com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving
        05-29 21:37:46.565: I/ActivityManager(289): Start proc com.appturbo.appturboCA for broadcast com.appturbo.appturboCA/com.appturbo.appturbo.services.InstallCatcher: pid=2402 uid=10145 gids={3003, 1015}
        05-29 21:37:46.575: I/RegisteredComponentCache(423): ComponentInfo: ResolveInfo{4053b070 com.android.apps.tag.TagViewer p=0 o=0 m=0x108000}, techs: android.nfc.tech.Ndef, 
        05-29 21:37:46.665: D/dalvikvm(289): GC_EXPLICIT freed 798K, 44% free 7540K/13319K, external 874K/2154K, paused 64ms
        05-29 21:37:46.665: D/AndroidRuntime(2387): Shutting down VM
        05-29 21:37:46.685: I/ApplicationPolicy(289): registerPackageChangeReceiver() onReceive: Broadcast Received for PKG:com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving
        05-29 21:37:46.685: I/DmAppInfo(289): getApplicationsList found row counts : 0 For Pkg : com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving
        05-29 21:37:46.685: D/szipinf(289): Initializing inflate state
        05-29 21:37:46.695: D/Launcher.LauncherModel(449): addPackageBackground. mApplicationsAdapter: 1080065728
        05-29 21:37:46.705: D/dalvikvm(2387): GC_CONCURRENT freed 105K, 70% free 316K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 0ms+0ms
        05-29 21:37:46.705: D/jdwp(2387): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
        05-29 21:37:46.705: D/dalvikvm(2387): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
        05-29 21:37:46.725: I/DebugDb(449): Adater pointer com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.ApplicationsAdapter@40607ec0 57
        05-29 21:37:46.725: I/DebugDb(449): Dump Adapter 56 com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.ApplicationInfo smartLiving -1 -1 -1 -1|-1|-1|-1|-1|0 com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.ApplicationInfo@40683418
        ...
        other phone apps show up here
        ...
        05-29 21:37:46.915: I/DebugPlacement(449): View = com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.MenuItemView@405c89e8 tag = com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.ApplicationInfo Messaging -1 -1 2 3|-1|-1|-1|-1|0 com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.ApplicationInfo@405d3288 Owner = com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.AppShortcutZone@40693c50
        05-29 21:37:46.915: I/DebugPlacement(449): View = com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.MenuItemView@40558ad8 tag = com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.ApplicationInfo Phone -1 -1 1 1|-1|-1|-1|-1|0 com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.ApplicationInfo@4060fd68 Owner = com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.AppShortcutZone@40693c50
        05-29 21:37:46.915: I/DebugPlacement(449): View = com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.MenuItemView@40537900 tag = com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.ApplicationInfo Contacts -1 -1 0 2|-1|-1|-1|-1|0 com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.ApplicationInfo@405bea98 Owner = com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.AppShortcutZone@40693c50
        05-29 21:37:47.005: I/ActivityThread(2413): Pub com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider: com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider
        05-29 21:37:47.005: I/StatusBarPolicy(404): onSignalStrengthsChanged
        05-29 21:37:47.035: D/GTalkService(2137): handlePackageInstalled: re-initialize providers
        05-29 21:37:47.035: D/GTalkService(2137): [RawStanzaProvidersMgr] ##### searchProvidersFromIntent
        05-29 21:37:47.035: D/GTalkService(2137): [RawStanzaProvidersMgr] no intent receivers found
        05-29 21:37:47.035: I/ActivityManager(289): Start proc com.google.android.partnersetup for broadcast com.google.android.partnersetup/.AppInstalledReceiver: pid=2434 uid=10068 gids={3003}
        05-29 21:37:47.085: I/DebugDb(449): UpdateDBTask Begin Saving to DB
        05-29 21:37:47.085: I/DebugFolder(449): Save Folder Data To DB
        05-29 21:37:47.085: I/DebugDb(449): UpdateDBTask End Saving to DB true
        05-29 21:37:47.085: I/DebugDb(449): Update app info -1 com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.ApplicationInfo smartLiving -1 3 6 -1|-1|-1|-1|-1|0 com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.ApplicationInfo@40683418
        05-29 21:37:47.105: I/DebugDb(449): UpdateDBTask Close DB
        05-29 21:37:47.145: I/ActivityThread(2434): Pub com.google.android.partnersetup.rlzprovider: com.google.android.partnersetup.RlzProvider
        05-29 21:37:47.145: I/ActivityThread(2434): Pub com.google.android.partnersetup.rlzappprovider: com.google.android.partnersetup.RlzAppProvider
        05-29 21:37:47.205: E/AlarmManagerService(289): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=0, 1369877882.217000000
        05-29 21:37:47.205: V/AlarmManager(289): Adding alarm Alarm{4098f6e8 type 0 com.android.vending} at 0
        05-29 21:37:47.235: D/AndroidRuntime(2419): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
        05-29 21:37:47.235: D/AndroidRuntime(2419): CheckJNI is OFF
        05-29 21:37:47.235: D/AndroidRuntime(2419): setted country_code = Canada
        05-29 21:37:47.235: D/AndroidRuntime(2419): setted sales_code = TLS
        05-29 21:37:47.235: D/AndroidRuntime(2419): found sales_code tag = <TLS>, </TLS> 
        05-29 21:37:47.235: D/dalvikvm(2419): creating instr width table
        05-29 21:37:47.305: W/ResourceType(289): Failure getting entry for 0x7f02000f (t=1 e=15) in package 0 (error -75)
        05-29 21:37:47.335: D/LibQmg_native(2419): register_android_app_LibQmg
        05-29 21:37:47.345: D/DeviceEncryption(2419): JNI: register_android_deviceencryption_DeviceEncryptionManager
        05-29 21:37:47.365: D/AndroidRuntime(2419): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
        05-29 21:37:47.375: I/power(289): acquire_cpu_max_lock: set 1512000
        05-29 21:37:47.375: D/InputTransport(289): Input channel constructed: name='40ca94d0 Starting com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving (server)', ashmemFd=288, receivePipeFd=292, sendPipeFd=291
        05-29 21:37:47.375: D/InputTransport(289): Input channel constructed: name='40ca94d0 Starting com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving (client)', ashmemFd=289, receivePipeFd=290, sendPipeFd=293
        05-29 21:37:47.375: D/AndroidRuntime(2419): Shutting down VM
        05-29 21:37:47.375: V/LauncherAppWidgetHostView(449): dispatchSaveInstanceState: widgetid=5 vid=-1
        05-29 21:37:47.375: D/dalvikvm(2419): GC_CONCURRENT freed 106K, 67% free 346K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 0ms+0ms
        05-29 21:37:47.375: I/ActivityManager(289): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving/.MainScreenActivity } from pid 2419
        05-29 21:37:47.375: D/PowerManagerService(289): acquireDVFSlock : level : 1,    timeMS : 3000
        05-29 21:37:47.375: I/WindowManager(289):   CREATE SURFACE Surface(name=Starting com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving, identity=45, mNativeSurface=0) IN SESSION android.view.SurfaceSession@4065be98: pid=289 format=-1 flags=0x0 / Window{40ca94d0 Starting com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving paused=false}
        05-29 21:37:47.375: I/Launcher(449): onPause. Launcher: 40678538
        05-29 21:37:47.385: D/dalvikvm(2419): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
        05-29 21:37:47.385: D/msm8660.gralloc(289): !@/dev/pmem: allocating pmem size=1536000, offset=8523776(0x821000)
        05-29 21:37:47.395: I/PhotoAppWidgetProvider(2121): onReceive
        05-29 21:37:47.395: I/PhotoAppWidgetProvider(2121): PauseSlideShow
        05-29 21:37:47.395: D/PhotoAppWidgetProvider(2121): onReceive End
        05-29 21:37:47.395: D/CalendarAppWidgetProviderAgenda(2129): ACTION_HOME_PAUSE: false
        05-29 21:37:47.405: D/GL
        ViewGroup(449): Skipped drawing due to suspendDrawingUntilResume()
        05-29 21:37:47.405: I/ActivityManager(289): Start proc com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving for activity com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving/.MainScreenActivity: pid=2461 uid=10094 gids={}
        05-29 21:37:47.425: I/OrientationDebug(289): [pwm] in updateOrientationListenerLp()
        05-29 21:37:47.425: V/OrientationDebug(289): in updateOrientationListenerLp(), Screen status=true, current orientation=-1, SensorEnabled=false
        05-29 21:37:47.425: I/OrientationDebug(289): [pwm] needSensorRunningLp(), return false #3
        05-29 21:37:47.436: I/Launcher(449): onWindowFocusChanged(false)
        05-29 21:37:47.436: V/SurfaceView(449): com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.GLSurfaceViewGroup$1@405ab0f8 got app visibiltiy is changed: false
        05-29 21:37:47.436: V/SurfaceView(449): com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.GLSurfaceViewGroup$1@405ab0f8 sends UPDATE_WINDOW_MSG
        05-29 21:37:47.446: I/GLThread(449): noticed surfaceView surface lost tid=15
        05-29 21:37:47.456: W/EglHelper(449): destroySurface()  tid=15
        05-29 21:37:47.476: D/GLSurfaceViewGroup(449): Skipped drawing due to suspendDrawingUntilResume()
        05-29 21:37:47.486: D/dalvikvm(2461): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 51K, 49% free 2745K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 32ms
        05-29 21:37:47.526: D/dalvikvm(2461): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 49% free 2745K/5379K, external 1000K/2280K, paused 27ms
        05-29 21:37:47.536: I/dalvikvm(2461): Could not find method android.view.View.animate, referenced from method com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving.MainScreenActivity$3.onVisibilityChange
        05-29 21:37:47.536: W/dalvikvm(2461): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3690: Landroid/view/View;.animate ()Landroid/view/ViewPropertyAnimator;
        05-29 21:37:47.536: D/dalvikvm(2461): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0027
        05-29 21:37:47.536: D/dalvikvm(2461): VFY: dead code 0x002a-0037 in Lcom/asymptoticnerds/smartliving/MainScreenActivity$3;.onVisibilityChange (Z)V
        05-29 21:37:47.536: D/dalvikvm(2461): VFY: dead code 0x0042-0044 in Lcom/asymptoticnerds/smartliving/MainScreenActivity$3;.onVisibilityChange (Z)V
        05-29 21:37:47.546: D/InputTransport(289): Input channel constructed: name='40c8cc08 com.asymptoticnerds.smartliving/
```

i think it is talking about this in the code:

```
 mSystemUiHider
                .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    // Cached values.
                    int mControlsHeight;
                    int mShortAnimTime;

                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                    public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                            // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                            // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                            // screen.
                            if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                                mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                            }
                            if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                                mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                        android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                            }
                            controlsView.animate()
                                    .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                    .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                        } else {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren't
                            // available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
                            // controls.
                            controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                        }

                        if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                            // Schedule a hide().
                            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

although i think this was generated by eclipse (when i made the application first)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What device are you testing on?

The [View.animate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#animate%28%29) method was added in API level 12 it seems. Perhaps your device is not high enough level to have it.

This seems like it shouldn't be possible because of your `if` statement but I wonder if there is something peculiar about your specific device and its version code.

Perhaps try logging `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`to see what you get.

For some reason or another though it seems like the version of the system on your device does not have access to the animate method that you are trying to call here:

```
controlsView.animate()
```